# phpmyadmin add text to a field

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, field

I want to add the text `fred` to products_head_keywords_tag field in the table products_description but I dont want to wipe out the rest of the text in that field.

The following wipes out the text and adds fred but I just want to add the text fred after the other text that is already in that field.

```
UPDATE products_description SET products_head_keywords_tag = "fred"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick in T-SQL:

```
update products_description SET products_head_keywords_tag = convert(nvarchar(max),products_head_keywords_tag) + 'fred'
```

I guess mysql will handle it very similar.

Edit: In MySQL concat() is the way to go:

```
UPDATE products_description SET products_head_keywords_tag = CONCAT(products_head_keywords_tag, 'fred')
```